Requests over Nxing Ingress blocks other requests
I have deployed Nginx ingress controller in Kubernetes.
There are two pods running on different nodes
Furthermore, I have configured three ingresses with these three paths:

/
/dashboard
/grafana

The following scenario leads to further requests being blocked until the first request is finished:
I make a request on / via the browser. This is sent to Pod A via Service A. Pod A makes time.sleep(60).
I then make a request on /dashboard. The dashboard does not load until the first request is completed.
As far as I understand, nginx should be able to process the requests in parallel. But somehow this does not seem to be the case.
I hope you can help me.
Many thanks in advance.

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further. What should I do when someone answers my question?

Sorry, I've only just got back from holiday. I'll test it in the next few days.

If you are having problems with your NGINX ingress controller that are preventing requests from being handled as intended please make sure that the Proxy-buffering should be disabled to process requests without waiting for the initial request to finish, and you can also use the particular annotations to regulate how requests are handled. For more details, see here.
Additionally you can try utilizing ingress controller annotations and server-snippet annotation, or you can override the current Nginx Ingress Controller's ConfigMap.

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't confirm whether the answer is correct or incorrect. When I tested it the last days/hours, I noticed the root problem. The pod B behind /dashboard makes a request on /, although it should not do this. But since Pod A is sleeping, it can't process the request and I had therefore drawn the wrong conclusion that NGINX ingress controller is blocking the new requests.
